# How to prevent cell double click in ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I want to use the `cellClicked($event)` function to handle clicks in my grid. I need to disable multiple clicks on the same cell to prevent superfluous backend calls. If I register an empty callback to the `onCellDoubleClick($event)` my problem is solved, but I want to find a more elegant solution.

Does ag-grid have an option to prevent double clicks for whole grids?

```js
this.gridOptions = <GridOptions> {
  ...
  onCellClicked: this.cellClicked.bind(this), // <-- Only one with supstance
  onGridReady: this.onGridReady.bind(this),
  onCellDoubleClicked: this.onCellDoubleClicked.bind(this) // <-- Empty function, feels hacky.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled it by creating a [custom component](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/).

```
@Component({
  template: `
  <button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="invokeParent()"</button>
  `
})

export class ChildComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  private isDisabled: boolean = false;
  private params: any;
  constructor() {}

  agInit(params: any) {
    this.params = params;
    if (this.params.value === true) {
      this.isDisabled = true;
    }
  }

  public invokeParent() {
    this.params.value === false ? this.isDisabled = true  : this.isDisabled = false;
    this.params.context.ParentComponent.parentMethod(this.params);
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return true
  }
}
```

In the parent component I created a method to perform the backend call.

Answer (score 0):

Use **"suppressClickEdit"** in-bound property of AgGrid:

```
<ag-grid-angular
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [suppressClickEdit]="true"
></ag-grid-angular>
```